# In django admin database I am not getting expected view

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-nested-admin

In django admin database I am not getting expected view. I am following the tutorials to make a quiz app in Django. I did exactly as shown in video but still I am not getting same output. I have attached the picture of expected view and picture of what I am getting.

Getting This:
[image]

Expecting This:
[image]

models.py (in quiz):

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    roll_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['timestamp',]
        verbose_name_plural = 'Quizzes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')
    label = models.CharField('Question', max_length=255)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    label = models.CharField('Answer', max_length=255)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField('Correct answer', default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

class QuizTaker(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_finished = models.DateTimeField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    quiz_taker = models.ForeignKey(QuizTaker,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quistion = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question.label
```

In admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
import nested_admin
from .models import Quiz, Question, Answer, QuizTaker, UserAnswer

# Register your models here.

class AnswerInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = Answer
    extra = 4
    max_num = 4

class QuestionInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = Question
    inline = [AnswerInline]
    extra = 5

class QuizAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    inline = [QuestionInline,]

class UserAnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserAnswer

class QuizTakerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inline = [UserAnswerInline,]

admin.site.register(Quiz,QuizAdmin)
admin.site.register(Question)
admin.site.register(Answer)
admin.site.register(QuizTaker,QuizTakerAdmin)
admin.site.register(UserAnswer)
```

In settings.py

"""

```
Django settings for assignment2 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'u1e72cel3t20c3m5wvetnl*7w6x8srf4f#ncx6x=7*0k-w^@%x'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'bootstrap4',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'quiz',
    'nested_admin',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'assignment2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'assignment2.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'assignment.routing.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'test'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'thanks'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS =  [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/
```

Comment: Did you try adding a new record in your db and check after it ?

Comment: Did try running makemigrations again?